# SVELTE: Show/Hide individual JSON populated elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, svelte

**The problem description:**

- Button 1 should show/hide only the data of floor 1.
- Button 2 should how/hide the data of floor 2.
- Button 3 should show/hide data of floor 3.

As it stands each button shows/hides everything.

I could repeat my code for each JavaScript object and it would work - but I want to abstract the repetition for any JSON object that is referenced.

I tried different things but gave up and decided to ask SO. Seeing the replies will help me "Think SVELTE"

https://svelte.dev/repl/6e498fa577674323b4a602b4b4b3acf2?version=3.53.1

```
<div class="parent-container">
  {#each rooms as room}
  <button on:click={showHide}>Floor number {room.floor} </button>

  {#if showState}
     <div class={showState}>
      <h2>{room.floor}</h2>
       {#each room.rooms as singleRoom}
    <div>
      <h2>{singleRoom.number}</h2>
      
    </div>

    {/each}
    </div>
    {/if}

    {/each}
</div>

<script>   

let showState = "hide";

function showHide(){
  showState = (showState ==="hide") ? "show" : "hide";
}

let rooms =[
  {
    floor:1,
    rooms:[{number:101},{number:102},{number:103}]
  },
  {
    floor:2,
    rooms:[{number:201},{number:202},{number:203}]
  },

    {
    floor:3,
    rooms:[{number:301},{number:302},{number:303}]
  },

]


</script>

<style>
  .hide{
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: (`{#if showState}` is pointless because it always evaluates to true. If anything it should be `{#if showState == 'show'}`.)

Comment: @Michael M. I did. I posted the question working on the project last week and just replied as this weekend I started up again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you want to "think Svelte", so I think the most idiomatic option would be to extract the logic for each floor into a new `Floor` component and let each instance manages its own state.

Honestly, I'm surprised no one else suggested this. Using this solution, you can have as many rooms as you want, and helps separate your code. You can do it like this:

[Run it on the Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/2f2352953ebf400e8613951ff1000135?version=3.53.1)

**App.svelte**

```html
<script>
    import Floor from './Floor.svelte';
    
    let rooms =[
      {
        floor:1,
        rooms:[{number:101},{number:102},{number:103}]
      },
      {
        floor:2,
        rooms:[{number:201},{number:202},{number:203}]
      },
    
        {
        floor:3,
        rooms:[{number:301},{number:302},{number:303}]
      },
    ];
</script>

<div class="parent-container">
  {#each rooms as room}
        <Floor room={room}/>
  {/each}
</div>
```

**Floor.svelte**

```
<script>
    export let room;
    
    let showState = false;
    function showHide() {
        showState = !showState;
    }
</script>

<style>
    .hide{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<button on:click={showHide}>Floor number {room.floor} </button>

{#if showState}
    <div class:hide={!showState}>
        <h2>{room.floor}</h2>
        {#each room.rooms as singleRoom}
            <div>
                <h2>{singleRoom.number}</h2>
            </div>
        {/each}
    </div>
{/if}
```

I also changed `showState` into a boolean. This makes it a bit easier to understand and follow along. Also, as [@Corrl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15388872/corrl) pointed out, it is better to use the `class:` directive instead of an if-statement.

Comment: Alternative to the ternary operator would be the class: directive `class:hide={!showState}` (Either class or if block would be enough though...)

Comment: @Corrl Good catch. I think that is more idiomatic too, so I've updated my answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

You currently only have one state for multiple objects. There are multiple ways of approaching this:

- Extract the content of the `#each` into a separate component, that way each object will have its own separate state
- Store the visibility alongside the data (if that is not an issue)
- Store the visibility in a separate object or array

E.g. storing the state in a separate array:

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  {#each rooms as room, i}
    <button on:click={() => showHide(i)}>Floor number {room.floor} </button>

    {#if visibility[i]}
      <div>
        <h2>{room.floor}</h2>
        {#each room.rooms as singleRoom}
          <div><h2>{singleRoom.number}</h2></div>
        {/each}
      </div>
    {/if}
  {/each}
</div>

<script>
  let rooms = [
    { floor: 1, rooms: [{number:101},{number:102},{number:103}] },
    { floor: 2, rooms: [{number:201},{number:202},{number:203}] },
    { floor: 3, rooms: [{number:301},{number:302},{number:303}] },
  ];

  let visibility = new Array(rooms.length).fill(false);

  function showHide(index) {
    visibility[index] = !visibility[index];
  }
</script>
```

Here the index provided by the `#each` is used to access the `visiblity` array.

Answer (score 1):

I like that @Michael M's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74608609/10735864) moves the floor logic and styling to its own floor component. That practice of component separation will make editing or reusing the code easier.

However, I also believe that less code is usually easier code. So I propose this somewhat simpler solution below (or try the [REPL here](https://svelte.dev/repl/14b5c0a414634e77af8d052b747136a3?version=3.53.1)) which adds visibility as an element to your floor data and allows your data to drive the logic instead of the other way around. This solution also makes use of Svelte's [inline handler functionality](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-on-eventname) if you'd like to read more about that. Hope this helps!

```
<div class="parent-container">
  {#each floors as floor}
        <button on:click={() => floor.visibility = floor.visibility * -1}>
            Floor number {floor.floor}
        </button>
        {#if floor.visibility === 1}
            <!--<div class=yourstyleclasshere>-->
                <h2>Floor: {floor.floor}</h2>
                    {#each floor.rooms as singleRoom}
                        <div>
                            <h2>{singleRoom.number}</h2>
                        </div>
                    {/each}
            <!--</div>-->
        {/if}
  {/each}
</div>

<script>   
let floors = [
  {
    floor:1,
    rooms:[{number:101},{number:102},{number:103}],
    visibility: -1
  },
  {
    floor:2,
    rooms:[{number:201},{number:202},{number:203}],
    visibility: -1
  },

    {
    floor:3,
    rooms:[{number:301},{number:302},{number:303}],
    visibility: -1
  }
]
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to use array to set showState for each room and use attribute to store floor number and get it with `this.getAttribute('attr-data-floor')` on event:

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  {#each rooms as room}
  <button on:click={showHide} attr-data-floor={room.floor}>Floor number {room.floor} </button>

  {#if showState[room.floor] }
     <div class={showState[room.floor]}>
      <h2>{room.floor}</h2>
       {#each room.rooms as singleRoom}
    <div>
      <h2>{singleRoom.number}</h2>
      
    </div>

    {/each}
    </div>
    {/if}

    {/each}
</div>

<script>   

let showState ={1:"hide", 2:"hide",3:"hide"} ; //one mor because 0

function showHide(){
    let num = this.getAttribute('attr-data-floor') ;
  showState[num] = (showState[num] ==="hide") ? "show" : "hide";
}

let rooms =[
  {
    floor:1,
    rooms:[{number:101},{number:102},{number:103}]
  },
  {
    floor:2,
    rooms:[{number:201},{number:202},{number:203}]
  },

    {
    floor:3,
    rooms:[{number:301},{number:302},{number:303}]
  },

]


</script>

<style>
  .hide{
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```